# Why isn't the key monitor working?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard

I am trying to set up a key monitor but it does not seem to work. I have the mask set up to listen for every possible event, however it does not recognize key events. Can somebody please tell me if I am missing something or if I am making some mistake.

```
int mask = NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSMouseMovedMask | NSScrollWheelMask | NSKeyDownMask | NSMouseMovedMask | NSEventTypeBeginGesture | NSEventTypeEndGesture;

self.keyMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:mask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
    NSLog(@"Event Occured");
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Cocoa Event-Handling Guide: Monitoring Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3)":

> A global event monitor looks for user-input events dispatched to applications other than the one in which it is installed. The monitor cannot modify an event or prevent its normal delivery. And **it may only monitor key events if accessibility is enabled or if the application is trusted for accessibility**.